# Queryset from non-related model in __init__ modelform method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have two model classes. They are not related models (no relationship).

```
# models.py

class Model1(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    option = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return self.option

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

I have respective form from where I am submitting and saving data in my table. I want to use my Model2 data to fill-in 'option' field as select field, so I am introducing below **init** method.

```
# forms.py

class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        all_options = Model2.objects.all()
        super(Model1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['option'].queryset = all_options

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('description', 'option')
```

It does not render the dropdown on my template, so I am wondering whether it is right way to address the issue (acknowledging that models are not related to each other).

Comment: A `ChoiceField` has no `.queryset`, only a `ModelChoiceField` has. You should work with a `ForeignKey` from `Model1` to `Model2`.

Comment: Thanks Willem! Appreciate your help and guidance!